# How do I change multiple data channels in Visio 2016

Tags: svg, visio

Right now, we are using Visio to export a table to an svg file with Visio data. The basic layout is 3 columns, and any number of rows. The columns are labelled "Name", "Status", "Origin". The name column are filled with different systems, like "admin1", "admin2", etc.

In addition, each Cell has two shape datas in them. Color data (a custom icon we have to change the color of the cell, changing the coloring rule) and a text box with a data channel.

We have over 60 rows in some of these tables, which means that we have to manually set the two shape datas 180 times. We figured out how to mass change the coloring rule, because each shape has the same rule. But we are having an issue finding out how to change the data channel. The convention we are using is systemname_columnname (ex - admin1_status).

So with all of the background information out of the way, is it possible to name the data channels quickly? One of the things we thought about was setting up naming all the data channels in Excel (since it would be easier in there) and then import the Excel sheet, but we haven't been able to figure out how to do that. There were a few sites I found that mentioned using the "Data" tab in Visio, but I haven't been able to find it when I try to edit my ribbon. Another thing we thought about was making a VB Script in Visio, but we haven't explored that option too much, hoping to find a way to use Excel.

Answer (score 0):

1. What is a data channel?
2. If you don't have a professional version of Visio, you won't have the built-in data connectivity. But you can easily write your own import/export function in VBA.